# Combine Two Lists in python in dataframe with file name added in one column and content in another

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a list of files in a folder in my system

```
file_list= ["A", "B", "C"]
```

I Have read the files using a for loop and have obtained content which is as follows

```
A = ["A1", "B1", "C1"]
B = ["E1", "F1"]
C = []
```

I would like the following output

```
    Content  Name
      A1     A
      B1     A
      C1     A
      D1     B
      E1     B
             C
```

How do I accomplish this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
import pandas as pd

data = list(zip((A, B, C), file_list))

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Content', 'Name'])
df = df.explode('Content')
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
  Content Name
0      A1    A
0      B1    A
0      C1    A
1      E1    B
1      F1    B
2     NaN    C
```

Comment: Thank you. Creates a dynamic combination of data using list(zip....