# Create a dataframe and populate the same using for loops in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I have three lists in Python that are made of character vectors

```
 A=["A1", "B1", "C1"]
 B=["E1", "F1"]
 C=[]
```

I have created a list using this as follows

```
  import pandas as pd
  files_list=[]
  files_list.append(A)
  files_list.append(B) 
  files_list.append(C)
```

I am trying to create the following dataframe

```
   Value    Index
   A1       A
   B1       A
   C1       A
   D1       B
   E1       B
            C
```

I have used the following loop

```
 L = pd.DataFrame()
 for file in files_list:
             page = file
             for j in page:
             #print (j)
             L["Value"]=j
             L["Index"]=file
```

I am not getting the desired output but an error saying Length of values (2) does not match length of index (3).

I also tried the following code

```
 L = pd.DataFrame()
    for file in files_list:
    page = file
    for j in page:
    data = list(zip((j), file))
```

This is also not yielding the required output and only lists few of the entries
I request someone to take a look

Comment: This did not answer you're question https://stackoverflow.com/q/63571922/4985099. How is this question different from you're previous post ?

Comment: Am trying it in a loop here. Or a dictionary. That solution works but its almost hardcoded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest create dictionary here and then flatten values to list of tuples passed to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
A=["A1", "B1", "C1"]
B=["E1", "F1"]
C=[]
  
d = {'A':A, 'B':B, 'C':C}

out = []
for x, y in d.items():
    if len(y) > 0:
        for a in y:
            out.append((a, x))
    else:
        out.append((np.nan, x))
print (out)
[('A1', 'A'), ('B1', 'A'), ('C1', 'A'), ('E1', 'B'), ('F1', 'B'), (nan, 'C')]

df = pd.DataFrame(out, columns=['Value','Value'])
print (df)
  Value Value
0    A1     A
1    B1     A
2    C1     A
3    E1     B
4    F1     B
5   NaN     C
```

Comment: Thank you. But why is my loop not working as expected.

Comment: @Raghavanvmvs - I think problem is in `dictionary`, how is created?

Comment: Alright. So i create a dictionary dynamically and then transform the same into a dataframe

Comment: @Raghavanvmvs - yes, it should be the best here, if problem with it please post your code for create it and I try help with it.